# ERROR: unexpected error - no such column: FALSE on dvc pull

Tags: dvc

dvc pull command fails with ERROR: unexpected error - no such column: FALSE
What could be the possible cause?

dvc pull command is executed semi-regularly. No changes to the model, config or model storage were made since last successful execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an older sqlite version installed. You could install older dvc version (2.45.1) or upgrade sqlite. Created https://github.com/iterative/sqltrie/issues/8 to avoid this problem in the next release.

Comment: @huehye please give 2.47.0 a try

Comment: If upgrading dvc doesn't work for you, try manually upgrading the `sqltrie` dependency: `pip install -U sqltrie`